# What does it mean to balance a redox reaction in acidic or basic mediums?

Tags: physical-chemistry, redox, stoichiometry

Until now it was clear to me what balancing a reaction was. Balancing redox reaction also make sense to me. What does it mean to balance a redox reaction in acidic or basic medium?

Comment: Well, some reactions may turn out different ways depending on the medium.

Comment: I think you are confused by the word "medium." Most of the reactions are carried out in the liquid phase. When you are able to adjust the pH of a liquid phase, and redox reaction occurs, one can talk about an "acidic or basic" medium.

Answer (score 2):

In acidic medium the equation must mention somewhere that some $\ce{H+}$ ions appear somewhere in the equation. In basic medium, the equation must mention somewhere that some $\ce{OH-}$ ions appear somewhere in the equation,

For example, you may say that permanganate ion reacts in acidic conditions to produce $\ce{Mn^2+}$. In basic conditions, it could not produce $\ce{Mn^2+}$, because this ion will react with $\ce{OH-}$ ions to produce a precipitate of $\ce{Mn(OH)2}$.

As an application, the permanganate ion reacts with oxalic acid $\ce{H2C2O4}$ in acidic conditions according to :

$$\ce{2 MnO4-  +  5 H2C2O4 +  6 H+ ->  2 Mn^2+  +  10 CO2  +   8 H2O}$$

Here, one sees that 6 ions $\ce{H+}$ are necessary for the reaction to happen. If no $\ce{H+}$ are present in the mixture permanganate + oxalic acid, this reaction cannot take place. Another reaction is produced without $\ce{H+}$. If you mix permanganate ion with oxalic acid in a basic solution, the first reaction that happen is the neutralization of the acid by the base namely :

$$\ce{H2C2O4  +  2 OH-  ->  C2O4^2-  + 2 H2O}$$

So, here, it is not oxalic acid that reacts with permanganate, but the oxalate ion $\ce{C2O4^2-}$. The reaction will be :

$$\ce{2 MnO4-  +  3 C2O4^2-  +  4 OH-  ->  2 MnO2  +  6 CO3^2-  +  2 H2O}$$

Here you see that some $\ce{OH-}$ are needed for the reaction to proceed. It cannot happen in acidic medium.

Comment: Protons or hydroxide ions must appear as reagents, if the solution is acidic or basic; not just somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Say we have a given redox reaction:
$$\ce{MnO4- + Fe^2+ -> Fe^3+ + Products}$$
This is an unbalanced redox reaction, just depicting how $\ce{Fe^2+}$ is oxidized to $\ce{Fe^3+}$ by $\ce{KMnO4}$. Now, depending on the medium, the following reactions may take place:

- In an acidic medium, $\ce{MnO4-}$ is reduced to $\ce{Mn^2+}$ by accepting 5 electrons
  $$\ce{MnO4- + 5Fe^2+ + 8H+ -> 5Fe^3+ + Mn^2+ + 4H2O}$$
- In a neutral/weakly basic medium, $\ce{MnO4-}$ is reduced to $\ce{MnO2}$ by accepting 3 electrons
  $$\ce{MnO4- + 3Fe^2+ + 2H2O -> 3Fe^3+ + MnO2 + 4OH-}$$
- In a strongly basic medium, $\ce{MnO4-}$ is reduced to $\ce{MnO4^2-}$ by accepting 1 electron
  $$\ce{MnO4- + Fe^2+ -> Fe^3+ + MnO4^2-}$$

This is just one example of how different mediums can affect a given redox process; other redox reactions may also be influenced, depending on whether the medium is acidic or basic.

Comment: In basic medium, $\ce{Fe^3+}$ does not exist. It is transformed in Fe(OH)3